# php __get method and visibility types behavior

Tags: php

```
class Magic{
    public $a="i";
    public $b=array("a"=>"A","b"=>"B","c"=>"C");
    public $c=array(1,2,3);

    public function __get($v)
    {
     echo "<br/>get->$v";
     return $this->b[$v];
    }

    public function __set($var,$val)
    {
    echo "<br/>set->$var: $val,";
    $this->$var=$val;
    }
    }

    $m=new Magic();
    echo $m->a." , ".$m->b." ,".$m->c." ,";
    $m->c="CC";
    echo $m->a." , ".$m->b." ,".$m->c;
```

**Output**:i , Array ,Array ,i , Array ,CC

Now, I modify the visibility to protected for variable $b and $c.

**Output**: bci , B ,C ,c: CC,bci , B ,C

As far as I understand _*get and*_set is called for undefined var .So, when access modifier or visibility is set to protected why __get() is called !.

Can someone explain ..... I am not able to understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members)

> __set() is run when writing data to inaccessible properties.
>
> __get() is utilized for reading data from inaccessible properties.

A protected / private property is considered inaccessible from an external scope.

Answer (score 1):

`__get()` is called everytime you try to access a non-public varialbe from the 'outside'. So that covers non-existing, protected and hidden properties.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above, comments.

When you set b and c to protected. It means, property a is visible when called like this:

echo $m->a; // direct access to public property.

However when $m->b and $m->c are echoed, it cannot find it because the visibility is available to only within the class. Luckily, __set() and __get() are implemented in your class.

So __get() is called when trying to echo (read) property and __set() is called when you try to assign property.

**One important tricky thing to note is that... the first line in __get() will overwrite the first portion of the echo ($m->a)...**

For more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

class Magic {

```
public $a="i";
protected $b=array("a"=>"A","b"=>"B","c"=>"C");
protected $c=array(1,2,3);

public function __get($v)
{
 echo "<br/>get->$v";
 return $this->b[$v];
}

public function __set($var,$val)
{
echo "<br/>set->$var: $val,";
$this->$var=$val;
}
}

$m=new Magic();
echo $m->a." , ".$m->b." ,".$m->c." ,";  // __get() called here only for b & c

$m->c="CC";  // __set() is called here for c

echo $m->a." , ".$m->b." ,".$m->c; // __get() is called here for b & c
```